# How do I loop through a cursor in Redshift?

Tags: cursors, redshift

Rather than pollute this thread with the dozens of different things I've tried, including using a stored procedure, dynamic SQL, etc., all of which results in one error or another, I will ask what is wrong with doing something like this:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cur_a CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM large_table;
LOOP
  FETCH FORWARD 10000 FROM cur_a;
  EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_a;
COMMIT;
```

But I get the following error:

```
BEGIN executed successfully

Execution time: 0.11s
Statement 1 of 7 finished

0 rows affected
DECLARE executed successfully

Execution time: 0.11s
Statement 2 of 7 finished

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
LOOP
  FETCH FORWARD 10000 FROM cur_a

ERROR: syntax error at or near "LOOP"
  Position: 2


LOOP
 ^

Execution time: 0.11s
Statement 3 of 7 finished
```

I want to declare a cursor, and loop through it 10,000 rows at a time, then close the cursor and end the transaction. Essentially, I want to output the table in 10,000 row chunks. Can someone please help me with how to do this in Redshift? Or is it not possible?

Comment: `LOOP` is not an SQL statement, it's a PL/pgSQL statement and can only be used in a [PL/pgSQL block](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html#r_PLpgSQL-block). I don't know if Redshift supports anonymous blocks, which is what you seem to be trying to create, but in any case your block structure is incorrect.

Comment: Also loops / cursors are typically not ideal from a performance perspective in most use cases with a relational programming language (SQL).

Comment: @J.D. I understand. This is meant to replicate specific behavior.